# ¿Por qué me sale el error "AAPT process not ready to receive commands " en Android 2.3?

Tags: android, ubuntu

Estoy trabajando con Android 2.3 en ubuntu 6.10, buildToolsVersion 25.0.2.

Cuando creo un nuevo proyecto me da el siguiente error:

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
> :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar,
> :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies] Error:Execution failed for task
> ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT process not ready to receive commands
> Information:BUILD FAILED Information:Total time: 28.146 secs
> Information:2 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete
> output in console

He leído que puede ser problemas del gradle pero como soy nuevo en esto no sé qué está pasando.

este es mi build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.jesus.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: que buildToolsVersion tienes ?

Comment: @Jorgesys 25.0.2

Comment: Prueba con lo que comento, esto se realizaba en Windows/Mac

Answer (score 0):

Este es un detalle que surgio cuando actualizamos el buildToolsVersion a 25, pero en el caso de una distribución linux podría ser que aún exista el problema, te sugiero bajar a la versión 23.0.3, temporalmente.

Descarga Build Tools 23.0.3:
 http://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r23.0.3-linux.zip

Extraelo dentro de la ubicación de tu SDK y el directorio `/buildtools`,  android-sdk/buildtools para reemplazar la versión actual 25.0.2.

Comment: Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0
<a href="fix.build.tools.version">Update Build Tools version and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:/home/jesus/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: me dice que es muy bajo :/

Comment: podrías agregar tu build.grade ?

Comment: ya, perdona es que soy nuevo usando esta pagina

Comment: gracias, ahora veo, debes cambiar las versiones a 23 en lugar de 25 para usar la versión 23 de  Build Tools.

Comment: me dice que la version de build 23 es muy bajo para el proyecto"app" que el minumo es 25